# Find an <a> with a specific name, and then click another <a> in that div

Tags: jquery

I have a series of div elements on my page which look like the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="child1">
    <a name="xyz"></a>
  <div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3">
    <a class="anch" onclick="func1()"></a>
    <a class="anch" onclick="func2()"></a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I now have a string in a variable which may match one of the `name` attributes in the `div.child1` nested anchor. I need to loop through all those anchors in all the `div.wrap` elements and if the variable matches the anchor name, to then automatically click the second anchor in `div.child3` (func2).

Is there any (relatively) easy way to do this in jquery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ˙˙˙˙¿ **ʇɐɥʍ** **WHAT** ?....

Comment: I don't think this question needs closing... it just needs the OP to reword it to make a bit more sense. Although I think I understood it alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[name=xyz]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.child3 a').eq(1).trigger('click');
});
```

​
`.eq()` refers to the element index, which is zero based, so element two is actually index 1.

This [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/r3vvr/) shows it working.

I did add `href="#"` to your links, as I don't think jQuery (or maybe generic) click handlers allow the click event on an anchor tag without a href attribute.

**Edit**

This can be made dynamic by simply using a string to store the name, then manipulate the selector based on that variable:

```
var name = 'xyz';

$('a[name=' + name + ']')...
```

The following [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/beneverard/r3vvr/1/) is modified to show this.

Comment: Ben, thanks for your reply. The string I have is dynamically generated and is in a variable. How do I put that variable into your code for the comparison?

Comment: Check my edited answer, is that what you were referring to?